# ANDROID - HILT - ViewModel between activity - Compose Navigation - Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am learning how to use HILT and i am learning how to use Compose navigation too, so i am encountering this situation.

I haves this ViewModel.

```
@HiltViewModel
class PaymentFlowViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
private val _amount = MutableLiveData<String>()
val amount: LiveData<String> = _amount

fun setAmount(newAmount: String) {
    _amount.value = newAmount
}
}
```

I have This Activity where i have in the compose function my Navigation component. The annotation of AndroidEntryPoint is there.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class PaymentActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private val viewModel: PaymentFlowViewModel by viewModels()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val amount = intent.getStringExtra("amountKey")
    viewModel.setAmount(amount ?: "0000")

    setContent {
        M3ComponentsTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                PaymentFlow()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And my PaymentFlow is like this.

```
@Composable
fun PaymentFlow() {
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "SelectPaymentType") {
    composable("SelectPaymentType") { SelectPaymentTypeScreen(navController) }
    composable("cardReader") { CardProcessScreen(navController) }
}
}
```

So when i start the activity it goes to the PaymentFlow() and start in the SelectPaymentTypeScreen.
In that screen i have the ViewModel like this.

```
@Composable
fun SelectPaymentTypeScreen(
navController: NavController,
paymentViewModel: PaymentFlowViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val activity = if (context is Activity) context else null
val amount = paymentViewModel.amount.value
```

And in that point the viewModel is a new instance of the one from the activity.

I tested something, if i use in the activity the SelectPaymentTypeScreen() composable WITHOUT going to the PaymentFlow() it works perfectly. I dont know how to get it work with the PaymentFlow() navigation.

Maybe i can pass the viewModel in the arguments in paymentFlow but if i am not wrong that is one of the benefits of using HILT, not passing things by arguments repetidly.

Answer (score 0):

When you get `PaymentFlowViewModel` with `hiltViewModel()` inside the navigation graph it retuns an instance scoped to the navigation destination of `SelectPaymentTypeScreen`, unlike the instance you created in the `PaymentActivity`. Instead of trying to access `PaymentFlowViewModel` before its intended lifecycle, you could pass the data as a navigation argument. A detailed explanation can be found in the [Official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/type-safety).

```
@Composable
fun PaymentFlow(start_amount: String) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "SelectPaymentType/{start_amount}"
    ) {
        composable(
            route = "SelectPaymentType/{start_amount}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("start_amount") {
                type = NavType.StringType; defaultValue = start_amount
            }),
        ) { SelectPaymentTypeScreen(navController) }
        composable("cardReader") { CardProcessScreen(navController) }
    }
}
```

And in the `ViewModel`

```
    init {
        val startAmount = savedStateHandle.get<String>("start_amount")
        _amount.value = startAmount
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single activity why don't you use activityviewmodel that will return the same instance of the ViewModel you created in your activity?

paymentViewModel: PaymentFlowViewModel = activityViewModels()